# SQL select ids with columns that has a least two tags

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I am working on job related data and wanted to do some analysis.

I have two tables a Job table with job_id and an Application table with app_id,job_id,tag.

I want to select all job_ids that have an application with at least one tag with the name -> 'hired' AND at least one tag with the name 'not hired'. May I know how do i do this in Postgresql?

Job Table

| job_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Application table

| app_id | job_id | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | hired |
| 2 | 1 | not hired |
| 3 | 2 | hired |
| 4 | 2 | hired |
| 5 | 3 | not hired |
| 6 | 3 | not hired |

In this case i want my output to be

| job_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

job_id 2 and 3 is not included because it does not have at least 1 hired and at least 1 not hired in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate all tags into an array, then test if at least the two arrays you are after are included in that:

```
select job_id
from application
group by job_id
having array_agg(tag) @> array['hired', 'not hired']
```

If you need columns from the job table as well, you can join the result to it:

```
select j.*
from job j
join ( 
  select job_id 
  from application
  group by job_id
  having array_agg(tag) @> array['hired', 'not hired']
) a on a.job_id = j.job_id
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1803959955616039fc0814abb4eb342d)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to achieve it ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/odhVvvmWuBksL672sSuVLr/1))

```
with x as (select distinct job_id,tag from application)
select job_id
from x
group by job_id
having count(*) > 1
```

or you can use subqueries

```
select job_id
from (select distinct job_id,tag from application) x
group by job_id
having count(*) > 1;
```